# Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) No implementation of function Function

Tags: python, numba

TypingError

```
During: typing of setitem 
def calc_ppr_topk_parallel(indptr, indices, deg, alpha, epsilon, nodes, topk):
    <source elided>
        idx_topk = np.argsort(val_np)[-topk:]
        js[i] = j_np[idx_topk]
        ^
```

```
import numba
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp


@numba.njit(cache=True, locals={'_val': numba.float32, 'res': numba.float32, 'res_vnode': numba.float32})
def _calc_ppr_node(inode, indptr, indices, deg, alpha, epsilon):
    alpha_eps = alpha * epsilon
    f32_0 = numba.float32(0)
    p = {inode: f32_0}
    r = {}
    r[inode] = alpha
    q = [inode]
    while len(q) > 0:
        unode = q.pop()

        res = r[unode] if unode in r else f32_0
        if unode in p:
            p[unode] += res
        else:
            p[unode] = res
        r[unode] = f32_0
        for vnode in indices[indptr[unode]:indptr[unode + 1]]:
            _val = (1 - alpha) * res / deg[unode]
            if vnode in r:
                r[vnode] += _val
            else:
                r[vnode] = _val

            res_vnode = r[vnode] if vnode in r else f32_0
            if res_vnode >= alpha_eps * deg[vnode]:
                if vnode not in q:
                    q.append(vnode)

    return list(p.keys()), list(p.values())

@numba.njit(cache=True)
def calc_ppr(indptr, indices, deg, alpha, epsilon, nodes):
    js = []
    vals = []
    for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
        j, val = _calc_ppr_node(node, indptr, indices, deg, alpha, epsilon)
        js.append(j)
        vals.append(val)
    return js, vals


@numba.njit(cache=True,locals={'j_np': numba.int64,'val_np': numba.int64})
def calc_ppr_topk_parallel(indptr, indices, deg, alpha, epsilon, nodes, topk):
    js = [np.zeros(0, dtype=np.int64)] * len(nodes)
    vals = [np.zeros(0, dtype=np.float32)] * len(nodes)
    for i in numba.prange(len(nodes)):
        j, val = _calc_ppr_node(nodes[i], indptr, indices, deg, alpha, epsilon)
        j_np, val_np = np.array(j), np.array(val)
        idx_topk = np.argsort(val_np)[-topk:]
        js[i] = j_np[idx_topk]
        vals[i] = val_np[idx_topk]
    return js, vals


def ppr_topk(adj_matrix, alpha, epsilon, nodes, topk):
    """Calculate the PPR matrix approximately using Anderson."""

    out_degree = np.sum(adj_matrix > 0, axis=1).A1
    nnodes = adj_matrix.shape[0]

    neighbors, weights = calc_ppr_topk_parallel(adj_matrix.indptr, adj_matrix.indices, out_degree,
                                                numba.float32(alpha), numba.float32(epsilon), nodes, topk)

    return construct_sparse(neighbors, weights, (len(nodes), nnodes))


def construct_sparse(neighbors, weights, shape):
    i = np.repeat(np.arange(len(neighbors)), np.fromiter(map(len, neighbors), dtype=np.int))
    j = np.concatenate(neighbors)
    return sp.coo_matrix((np.concatenate(weights), (i, j)), shape)


def topk_ppr_matrix(adj_matrix, alpha, eps, idx, topk, normalization='row'):
    """Create a sparse matrix where each node has up to the topk PPR neighbors and their weights."""

    topk_matrix = ppr_topk(adj_matrix, alpha, eps, idx, topk).tocsr()

    if normalization == 'sym':
        # Assume undirected (symmetric) adjacency matrix
        deg = adj_matrix.sum(1).A1
        deg_sqrt = np.sqrt(np.maximum(deg, 1e-12))
        deg_inv_sqrt = 1. / deg_sqrt

        row, col = topk_matrix.nonzero()
        # assert np.all(deg[idx[row]] > 0)
        # assert np.all(deg[col] > 0)
        topk_matrix.data = deg_sqrt[idx[row]] * topk_matrix.data * deg_inv_sqrt[col]
    elif normalization == 'col':
        # Assume undirected (symmetric) adjacency matrix
        deg = adj_matrix.sum(1).A1
        deg_inv = 1. / np.maximum(deg, 1e-12)

        row, col = topk_matrix.nonzero()
        # assert np.all(deg[idx[row]] > 0)
        # assert np.all(deg[col] > 0)
        topk_matrix.data = deg[idx[row]] * topk_matrix.data * deg_inv[col]
    elif normalization == 'row':
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown PPR normalization: {normalization}")

    return topk_matrix
```

`

I think I went about it the wrong way.

TypingError: invalid setitem with value of array(int32, 1d, C) to element of array(int64, 1d, C)
This code is in the pprgo algorithm model, but when I run this error, it should not be the author's error. The algorithm prototype :https://github.com/TUM-DAML/pprgo_pytorch
Is there a simple way to change the data type to the same one?Can we use it without numba acceleration ,as long as it works?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a dictionairy inside of a numba function. As numba only has very limited support for dictionaries, the code crashes. The error message implies that there is another problem with the code aswell, but without any input given I am not going to bother trying to find it.

It looks like you have also tried to give a lot of keywords to numba, some of which do not seem to be doing anything, such as the `cache` keyword. I get the feeling that you just grabbed your (large) function and tried to apply numba to it.

This is not the way to go, as numba has quite a bit of a learning curve to use correctly. I suggest that you try to get a very small function to work first, and then try to expand it until you have your original function.

Also dictionaries are generally a bad idea if you want to write high perfomance code.

Comment: The main problem is TypingError: invalid setitem with value of array(int32, 1d, C) to element of array(int64, 1d, C) in function calc_ppr_topk_parallel：  js[i] = j_np[idx_topk]，Is there a simple way to change the data type to the same one？

Comment: I made a little addition to the above, you can have a look.thank you for your advice.

Comment: @JoyboySimba your code still uses a dictionary, and I am not going to rewrite that entire piece of code for you. Also, using append is very slow, as you are making a copy of the list everytime. It is better to create a empty list, and then fill it in with values. Good luck!